# HttpClient and using proxy - constantly getting 407

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpclient

Here is the code:

```
 HttpClient client = null;
 HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
    Proxy = new WebProxy(string.Format("{0}:{1}", proxyServerSettings.Address, 
    proxyServerSettings.Port),false),
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
 };


 this.httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyServerSettings.UserName, 
                        proxyServerSettings.Password);


 this.client = new HttpClient(this.httpClientHandler);
```

And when I finally do this:

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = this.client.PostAsync(urlToPost, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, this.mediaType)).Result;
```

It always throws the

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication
>   Required.

Which I do not understand for the world of me.

The same proxy set up works just fine when is configured in IE10 or if I use the `HttpWebRequest` class instead

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You're setting the proxy credentials in the wrong place.

httpClientHandler.Credentials are the credentials you give to the **server** after the proxy has already established a connection. If you get these wrong, you'll probably get a 401 or 403 response.

You need to set the credentials given to the **proxy**, or it will refuse to  connect you to the server in the first place. The credentials you provide to the proxy may be different from the ones you provide to the server. If you get these wrong, you'll get a 407 response. You're getting a 407 because you never set these at all.

```
// First create a proxy object
var proxy = new WebProxy
{
    Address = new Uri($"http://{proxyHost}:{proxyPort}"),
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,

    // *** These creds are given to the proxy server, not the web server ***
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        userName: proxyUserName,
        password: proxyPassword)
};

// Now create a client handler which uses that proxy
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = proxy,
};

// Omit this part if you don't need to authenticate with the web server:
if (needServerAuthentication)
{
    httpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
    httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    // *** These creds are given to the web server, not the proxy server ***
    httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        userName: serverUserName,
        password: serverPassword);
}

// Finally, create the HTTP client object
var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
```

Comment: I am getting  Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid. exception in Mono

Comment: You have to change `Address = new Uri($"http://{proxyHost}:{proxyPort}"),` . If you get URI error.

Comment: @Daryl how I can make the proxy as optional for every request? for example I have checkbox which is enable proxy or disable

Comment: It works for me on desktop and server proxies where server doesn't have internet

Answer (score 24):

You need to pass a proxy Handler. try this it worked for me

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync();
```

Comment: I've found this answer simple and fast fix to apply. tnx

Answer (score 1):

I found some useful information about this [here from social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c06d3032-dceb-4a1a-bb6a-778fd13a938a/407-proxy-authentication-required). From the replies, tests I made and research into the [System.Net.WebProxy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to pass the proxy credentials into the proxy object, not the HttpClientHandler.

```
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(string.Format("{0}:{1}", proxyServerSettings.Address, 
    proxyServerSettings.Port),false),
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(proxyServerSettings.UserName, 
                    proxyServerSettings.Password),
};
```

This actually is meant to authenticate the connection to the proxy, not the HttpClientHandler.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
//const string address = "127.0.0.1:13566";
const string address = "[::1]:13566";
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
using HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri($"http://{address}"),
    },
    UseProxy = true,
    DefaultProxyCredentials = networkCredential,    
};
using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, false);
```

And proxy must follow [rfc7235 section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.3)
[Here](https://github.com/tqk2811/TqkLibrary.Proxy/blob/1d58067205c1f81f2ed5c4d0f3059ae5fe51eb1b/ConsoleTest/Program.cs#L49) my test

```http
[::1]:9775 >> POST http://httpbin.org/post HTTP/1.1
[::1]:9775 >> Host: httpbin.org
[::1]:9775 >> Accept: application/json
[::1]:9775 >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
[::1]:9775 >> Content-Length: 9

[::1]:9775 << HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
[::1]:9775 << Proxy-Authenticate: Basic Scheme='Data'

[::1]:9776 >> POST http://httpbin.org/post HTTP/1.1
[::1]:9776 >> Host: httpbin.org
[::1]:9776 >> Accept: application/json
[::1]:9776 >> Proxy-Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
[::1]:9776 >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
[::1]:9776 >> Content-Length: 9

httpbin.org << POST /post HTTP/1.1
httpbin.org << Host: httpbin.org
httpbin.org << Accept: application/json
httpbin.org << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
httpbin.org << Content-Length: 9
[[::1]:9776 >> httpbin.org] 9 bytes

httpbin.org >> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
httpbin.org >> Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2022 06:40:47 GMT
httpbin.org >> Content-Type: application/json
httpbin.org >> Content-Length: 384
httpbin.org >> Connection: keep-alive
httpbin.org >> Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
httpbin.org >> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
httpbin.org >> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
[[::1]:9776 << httpbin.org] 384 bytes
```