# ASP core 2.0 how to make a Http request when your working behind a proxy Server

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, http-proxy

This is how I am making requests, I am getting blocked by the proxy server.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = CreateHttpReq(new Uri(newUri));
HttpClient().SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It's also an authenticated proxy server so I need to pass username and password. Sorry if my question is vague newbie to asp core. Thanks in advance

Comment: well how is it authenticating you? http basic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856543/httpclient-and-using-proxy-constantly-getting-407 worked for me. Thank you