C# HttpClient WebProxy username parameters weird behaviour vs WebRequest
I need to authenticate my proxy with additional parameters in the Username field for the proxy. When I'm using HttpClient the parameters aren't being sent, when I use WebRequest it works.
HttpClient, the parameter-123 is ignored:
 HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyhost...");
                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name-test-parameter-123", "password");
                    httpClientHandler.Proxy = proxy;

HttpWebRequest works:
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyhost...");
                    myproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name-test-parameter-123", "password");
                    request.Proxy = myproxy;

It should use the parameters in the proxy username field but it doesn't

See this link for setting proxy credentials and httpclienthandler credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856543/httpclient-and-using-proxy-constantly-getting-407
